# Difference between AssemblyTitle and AssemblyName in a dotnet core application

Tags: c#, .net-core, process, csproj

Can somebody help me figure out the difference between `AssemblyName` and `AssemblyTitle` properties in a .NET Core `.csproj` file. I always had a picture in my mind that `AssemblyTitle`  has got to do with the display name of the process in the task manager and `AssemblyName` has got to do with the name of the executable itself and it's associated with the process name. Also, the process is identified with the `AssemblyName` itself rather than the `AssemblyTitle`. Am I right or is there something more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AssemblyTitle` - The assembly title is a friendly name, which can include spaces.

In Windows Vista, the information specified for this attribute appears on the Details tab of the Windows File Properties dialog box for the assembly. The property name is File description. In Windows XP, this information appears on the Version tab of the Windows File Properties dialog box. In all systems is part of the title bar and task manager process name.

AssemblyTitle consists of a single string - `Title`

`AssemblyName` - The assembly name is the internal name of the assembly that can be different from the title and can be acquired used via Reflection [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyname.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1). Can be also null.

AssemblyName contains multiple fields, which can be all acquired via FullName property.

```
Name: Example
Version: 1.0.0.2001
CultureInfo: en-US
FullName: Example, Version=1.0.0.2001, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=null
```

Comment: This should really cite references and quote copied text

Comment: That's what it does, the Example in question is outside of the scope of the question.